# I have a c# a console app that I need to convert to an Azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, console-application

I have a console app which (simplified) takes the response of a sql query and dumps it into a CSV file.

This needs to be run once a day, and I have been asked to convert app to an Azure managed function.

I added an Azure function timer project to my solution, added the dependency/reference to my console app cproj (in the same solution).  Then I added a line to the AzureFuntion Run method to execute the ConsoleAapp.Main().

(Intelisense is all happy)

I run it locally and it bombs out with an error that it can’t find the project/method at the path provided (which is correct; I verified.)

This will eventually be deployed to the cloud; but I don't have access to the Azure portal; have never developed for Azure, so I am flying blind in a sense because all the documentation/tutorials start with or exclusively develop in the portal.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

per [CrowCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276469/crowcoder): Move your code from the console app into a class library or even into the function app. itself.

Changing the console app .cproj to a class library did the trick!